# Can Someone Explain this regex snippet?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I found this replace code with what looks like regular expressions in them but I can't decipher the

```
new Date().toISOString().
  replace(/[z|t|\.]/gim," ").
  replace(/\d{3}\s$/gim, " ").
  replace(/:\d{2}\s+$/, " ").
  trim() + "\n")
```

sorry if that's vague. I'm not really sure what I am looking at

Comment: I'm looking now, but for your own understanding you can always plug it into https://regex101.com/ and it'll help you see what's going on.

Comment: oh wow I didn't know that site existed. That's really helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code

```
new Date().toISOString()
```

generates something that looks like this

```
2015-07-01T17:21:22.123Z
```

The regex will put it into the format

```
2015-07-01 17:21
```

All of the regex has the flags `g`, `m`, and `i`. Straight from regex101 this means:

> g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
>
> i modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])
>
> m modifier: multi-line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)

The first regex

```
[z|t|\.]
```

actually already has a mistake. Whoever wrote it assumed that `|` means `or` but this is not the case inside the square brackets. It could be better written as

```
[zt\.]
```

This will match 2015-07-01`T`17:21:22`.`123`Z` and then the replace

```
replace(/[z|t|\.]/gim," ")
```

will replace every character that matches that regex with a space. Giving you the new string

```
2015-07-01 17:21:22 123
```

The next regex `\d{3}\s$` matches and replaces 2015-07-01 17:21:22 `123` , giving you:

```
2015-07-01 17:21:22
```

Finally the regex `:\d{2}\s+$` matches and replaces  2015-07-01 17:21`:22` , giving you

```
2015-07-01 17:21
```

And then the extra spaces are trimmed off.

All in all this is not that great of a way to do what you want. You could probably either do it better with substrings or with momentjs as someone else already said.

Answer (score 2):

The ISO String date prints the date out in a format like:

```
2015-07-01T17:20:52.214Z
```

`/[z|t|\.]/` -- seems to be a mistype of `[zt.]` -- replace all "z", "t", or "." characters. `g` is global, `i` is case-insensitive, and `m` is multiline (useless here since the ISO date is only one line).  This applies to all the regexen.

This will replace the `T` before the time, the last `Z` with a space as well as the `.` before `214`.

`/\d{3}\s$/` -- 3 digits followed by a space anchored to the end of the line.  This replaces the `214` and the space that was added from the previous replacement.

`/:\d{2}\s+$/` -- a colon followed by two digits followed by one or more spaces anchored to the end of the line.  This replaces the `:52` (seconds part) as well as the space(s) added by previous replacements to the end.

`.trim` removes whitespace added to the end by the final replacement.  You end up with:

```
2015-07-01 17:20
```

...or the current year-month-day 24hours:minutes

This is fine, but multiple replacements probably aren't necessary.  If you need to do a lot of date formatting, I would recommend the [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) library which makes this kind of thing very easy.  You can also construct it from other date methods like `.getMonth`.

Comment: I know you can use momentjs but I'm learning and just working through the node.js tutorial. Also, isn't `[z|t|\.]` the same thing as `[zt.]`?

Comment: @SirParselot yes it is the exact same except that it will actually match the `|` character.

Answer (score 2):

A more readable way to do this would be:

```
var date = new Date().toISOString();
date = date.substr(0, 10) + ' ' + date.substr(11, 8);
```

Answer (score 1):

don't know the reason but can explain what replace is doing

```
  .replace(/[z|t|\.]/gim," ")  // replace with space any z,t or . 
                               // case insenzitive multiline

  .replace(/\d{3}\s$/gim, " ") // replace with space a group of 
                               // 3digits followed by 1 space at the 
                               // end of string

  .replace(/:\d{2}\s+$/, " ")  // replace the group of :, 2 digits 
                               // and at least 1 space from the tail 
                               // of string with space
```